# Restrict AWS Tag Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a way to create an AWS policy that would restrict an AWS tag name?

For example, if I wanted to create a tag namespace like:

```
admin.env.prod = true
user.system.profile = webserver
```

To prevent a user from creating a tag with name '`admin.*`' but allow '`user.*`' (or anything other than '`admin.*`' really).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not at this time. A user with the necessary permissions can set a tag value of anything on a resource as long as the tag meets the AWS [tag requirements](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/allocation-tag-restrictions.html). You could write a small script using [ec2-describe-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeTags.html) to periodically check your resource tags for compliance to your desired policy (perhaps using a regular expression?) and notify you if a bad tag name is found.